# Can not edit display name of list column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell, custom-list, metadata

I have a list where I am trying to edit the display name of some internal SharePoint fields, i.e. the "Title"-field.

I am using this code which runs, and gives no error, but it doesn't edit the display name of the column in the list.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "url"
$list = $web.Lists["listname"]
$column = $list.Fields["Title"]
$column.Title = "Edited name"
$column.Update()
```

If I use the GUI it works, but not by script - I need to make it work with the script. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to fix this. My code, and others provided here, do not work. The schema xml has to be edited, i.e. like this:

```
$w = get-spweb "http://pub.pdogs.local"
$l = $w.Lists["Simple List"]
$f = $l.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("MyCustomColumn")
if ($f -ne $null) {
    "$($f.SchemaXml)`n"
    $f.Title = "Changed via code 2"
    $xml = $f.SchemaXml
    $f.Title
    $f.TitleResource.Value
    "`n$xml`n"
    if ($xml -match "\s+DisplayName\s?=\s?`"([^`"]+)`"") {
        if ($matches[1] -ne $f.Title) {
            $xml = $xml -replace $matches[0], " DisplayName=`"$($f.Title)`""
            $f.SchemaXml = $xml
            $xml
        }
    }
}
$f.Update()
$w.Dispose()
```

Here is a full explenation for those interested:

https://platinumdogs.me/2014/01/13/setting-sharepoint-2013-columnfield-title-not-working-correctly/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity SiteURL 
$list = $web.Lists["List Title"] 
$fld = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title") 
$fld.Title = "Edited Title" 
$fld.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this didn't work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: yes.. i have tested it first in my environment..

Comment: I inspected with SharePoint manager, and the column was edited there. I then inspected the schema xml, there the display name was the old one, so I don't see it in the GUI. Maybe some update issues here. Butr very strange, indeed.

Comment: Dear @SID Did you consider that my edit is not useful for your answer ? I found the code format was not correct so I did changes !

Comment: Yes your edit is not useful.. Right answer is more important.. And dear if your edit is useful then i never raised question on your edit..

Comment: Yes @Ilyas, it's really strange..

Answer (score 1):

```
$column = $list.Fields["Internal Name"]
```

You should create the column object using internal name and not using title.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with your script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://devssite:1000/testSite/"
$list = $web.Lists["testList"]
$column = $list.Fields["Title"]
$column.Title = "Edited name"
$column.Update()
```

When you do `$column = $list.Fields["Title"]` its returning nothing. Its not even throwing error. You can test by printing `$column.Title` right after that.

Working and test solution:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://devssite:1000/testSite/"
$list = $web.Lists["testList"]
$column = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title")
$column.Title = "Edited name"
$column.Update()
```

You can see after `$column = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title")` this statement, if you evaluate `$column.Title` It will give you the title of the column.

This is also affecting the GUI. I just refreshed the screen after running powershell.

Comment: Hi. I tried that also before posting. This did not work for me. I had to do some changes in the schema xml to make it work.